# Truffle init not creating .sol files

Tags: javascript, nft

I'm using **Truffle** to create my project folder but when I run `truffle init`, the command creates the folders with no file in them, only *.gitkeep* file...

Is there an issue or the current version of truffle doesn't create automatically the *.sol* files etc.?

I'm using these libraries versions:

Truffle v5.5.31 (core: 5.5.31)
Ganache v7.4.3
Solidity - 0.8.17 (solc-js)
Node v16.14.2
Web3.js v1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Truffle removed the inclusion of `.sol` on `truffle init` since `v5.5.27`.

Now `truffle init` generates the empty folder structure and the git files you noted.

see: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5532